# Is there any difference to put \centering before \caption or after \caption?

Tags: tables, captions

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{"Title"}
\begin{tabular}
```

vs

```
\begin{table}
\caption{"Title"}
\centering
\begin{tabular}
```

Is there any difference between those two? I found that there is no difference, but I want to make sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no difference. `\caption` handles its own formatting. The `\centering` command is there to position the `tabular` environment only.